# Circular reference in Related tags section

Tags: discussion, search, new-nav, tag-search, related-tags

I've switched to new version of the navigation, and open questions related to [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)

[image]

In **Related Tags** section to the right I can see [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) at the first place. Maybe some redundancy here?

[image]

Comment: Do note that this is not just a [tag:python-2.7] issue.  All tags do this (well all the ones I have seen).  This also happens on meta tags

Comment: Oh, my bad, it's a dupe :( I'm sorry, guys.

Comment: No need to be sorry, unlike main, users on meta are friendly. *hides*